# How to loop audio with javax.sounds.sampled?

Tags: java, loops, audio, javasound

I have this code down for a background song for my GUI but it is too short so I was wondering if there would be a way to loop this? I tried putting it in a while loop but the program crashed

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException
{
    

    File file = new File("theme.wav");
    AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioStream);
    
    clip.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. You can use [`clip.loop(int count)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#loop-int-)!